# js/jquery add or remove value when enter text in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input with id = "input-price" and element span with some numerical value, e.g. 100. I would like that with each entered character in input, the value of 100 increased by 10 while when I remove the characters, the value decreases by 10. How to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by sign ?

Comment: I don't understand ?

Comment: I mean when i remove text from input, value of span element should decrease.

Comment: "when I remove the sign, the value decreases by 10" which sign are you talking about ?

Comment: so when you remove a character from the input the value decreases by 10 ?

Comment: For example when i enter 2 characters in input, value should be 100 + 10 + 10 = 120. But when i remove one char from input, value should be 120 - 10 = 110. Do you understand me ?

Comment: ok cool got it ! :)

Comment: You can set onChange on your input. Then each time you inpu change, you cat get string value from. Caculate it when string length increase or decrease

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```js
var priceInput = document.getElementById("input-price");

priceInput.addEventListener("input", representValue)

function representValue(){
   var numOfChars = priceInput.value.length;
   
   var magicSpan = document.getElementById("magic-value");
   value = 100 + (numOfChars*10);
   magicSpan.textContent = value;
}
```

```html
<span id="magic-value">100</span>
<input id="input-price" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way:

```js
var length = $('#input-price').val().length;
$('#input-price').on('input', function(){
  var n = Number($('#spanNumber').text());
  if(length < $('#input-price').val().length){
    $('#spanNumber').text(n + 10);
    length++
  }
  else{
    $('#spanNumber').text(n - 10);
    length--
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input-price"/>
<span id="spanNumber">100</span>
```